# Wikidata SPARQL query not returning a known match

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I was playing around on Wikidata trying to write a simple SPARQL query against a known match.  I can see from Arnold Schwartzeneggers page that his listed occupations include: Actor, Politician and Restaurater. When I write the simple query:

```
    #Items that have occupations of actor AND politician AND restauratuer 
    SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
           ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q33999.
           ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
           ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q3427922.

           SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
```

}

it returns Clint Eastwood (who also has these occupations) but no Arnold.  Can anyone point to any errors in this query?

Comment: I.e. just replace all occurences of `wdt:P106` with `p:P106/ps:P106`.

Comment: In addition to the correct hint of StanislavKralin, feel free to use the "fancy" power of Turtle syntax in SPARQL queries: `?item p:P106/ps:P106 wd:Q33999, wd:Q82955, wd:Q3427922 .`

Comment: Yes - that worked. Thank you both for your help on this!

Comment: @Asderex, also, `SELECT DISTINCT ... p:P106/ps:P106/(wdt:P279*) ...` gives two more results.

Comment: @Stanislav - thanks for the follow up suggestion.  These were great pointers for what I should be looking at.